How to debug reactive statements in shiny
I have a shiny app with a lot of inputs that are connected into different segments; data, plot, legends etc. All of these are stored in input$ and I would like to have a better overview so I create new values using reactive. For example
data_atr <- c("data_atr_1", "data_atr_2")
data_attributes <- map(data_atr, ~reactive({inputs[[.x]]})) |> setNames(data_atr)

Is this the "correct" way to do it or is there a better way? Because I would like to continue working with data_attributes as I would be using input
Second part of my question; How do you debug reactive values using browser()? Sometimes I need to debug my reactive values and when I try to print them to the console I get the following error:
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context.
• You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.

How do I print the values to the console?
I tried putting the browser() inside reactive, but nothing happened. I noticed when reactive is inside a function, then it enters debug (see below). Why is that? I'm also confused why I can print rv which is reactive without getting an error.
library(shiny)
library(purrr)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  numericInput("a", "a", 5), 
  numericInput("b", "b", 5), 
  textOutput("a_b")
)



server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal("test")
  
  a_b_fun <- function(input, names = c("a", "b")){
    
    reactive({
     # browser() THIS WORKS
      map(names, ~input[[.x]]) |> setNames(names)
      
    })
    
  } 
  
  f <- reactive({
    
  #  browser() # THIS DOES NOT WORK
    map(c("a", "b"), ~input[[.x]]) |> setNames(names)
    
    
  })
  a_b_reactive <- a_b_fun(input = input)
  a_b_sum <- eventReactive(a_b_reactive(), {
    a_b_reactive()$a + a_b_reactive()$b
    
  })
  
  output$a_b <- renderText(a_b_sum())
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server) 


Please see {reactlog}.

If you put browser() somewhere in your server and it doesn't stop execution, it is most probably because the reactive you put it on is not being executed by your app.
In your example, a_b_fun is used for a_b_sum, and a_b_sum is outputted as "a_b", so putting a browser() in a_b_fun will work as intended, and will stop execution of the app when that reactive is evaluated.
But, in your example, the reactive f is not used anywhere in your app, so it doesn't even run, therefore browser() never gets evaluated. In Shiny, only the reactive objects that are actually used for something in your app (like used by other reactives, or used for outputs) are executed, so putting browser() in an unused reactive will do nothing.
To get browser() working in the f reactive, use f for a test output, like output$f <- renderText(f()), and assign the output in your UI, so that piece of code is run and browser will stop execution.
Another good tip for debugging Shiny apps is putting message() calls in your reactives and outputs. That way you will get messages in your console when each element is executed. You can also make reactives print data or text, but remember to assign the correct output for each reactive, so that they return what you expect:
f <- reactive({
    message("running f()") # show a message in console

  #  browser() # THIS DOES NOT WORK
    result <- map(c("a", "b"), ~input[[.x]]) |> setNames(names)
    
    print(result) # print result in console
    return(result)
  })

output$f <- renderText(f())

